# Getting type error when trying to instantiate a sinon anonymous stub

Tags: node.js, typeerror, sinon, stub, sinon-chai

I am using Node.JS v17.4.0 with `"sinon": "^13.0.1",`. A simple code snippet like the following:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
const stub = sinon.stub();
```

throws `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stub')`. What do I miss?

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. You need to create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `import * as _sinon from 'sinon';` fixes the problem.